# preg_match_all() & UTF8 characters issue - the easiest way to go around

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I need some easy (without mb_* and things like that) to go around this issue.
I've tried something like 
`preg_match_all('#[a-ząśćłóżźń]{3,}#', $text, $matches);` 
but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
preg_match_all('#[a-z\x{0105}\x{015B}\x{0107}\x{0142}\x{00F3}\x{017C}\x{017A}\x{0144}]{3,}#uis', $text, $matches);
```

Comment: Throws an error like this "preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support /L, /l, /N{name}, /U, or /u at offset 6"

Comment: Actually you have to use `\x{hhhh}`.

Comment: Now, there isn't the error, but the pattern doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @daroPL Gumbo is right. It should look like this: `#[a-z\x{0105}\x{015B}\x{0107}\x{0142}\x{00F3}\x{017C}\x{017A}\x{0144}]{3,}#uis`

Answer (score 3):

Use `u` modifier. For instance:

```
preg_match_all('#[a-ząśćłóżźń]{3,}#u', $text, $matches);
```

Comment: I've tried it as well, but it throws an error like "preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 4".

Comment: @daroPL Are you sure your file with this PHP script is in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @daroPL Yeah, Timur is right. PHP file should be saved in UTF-8 using your text editor.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I saved it in UTF8 (without BOM) and goes perfectly. However, is there any way to do that without saving the file in UTF8?

Comment: @daroPL Then you need to escape byte sequences using hexadecimal notation. webarto gave an example :)